# Intellij Does not have run button when running Springboot Applications

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I downloaded Intellij to follow a Springboot tutorial. It begins by going to Spring Initializr to get all relevant dependencies in a folder and open it up on Intellij. As I open up Intellij, the run button is not visible. Instead it says "Add Configuration".

[image]

If I open up Intellij for a normal java program, I was easily able to click run and choose "Main.java"

[image]

This is a freshly installed Intellj and settings were set up as default. Is there a trick to find the run button when dealing with Springboot? I tried doing as if it was a normal program but as you can see, I can't find it. I tried looking up similar questions but there doesn't seem any that matches mine. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

EDIT 1:
I tried right clicking on src directory and select option Mark Directory As > Sources Root. But breaks program instead.

EDIT 2:
I tried adding a new configuration --> Add new --> Application --> then look for Main class entitled 'DemoApplication' but its not found. (I thought that this would be my main class)

Comment: Maybe after running it manually the first time (right-click the main class --> Run), it will appear afterwards ?

Comment: @Arnaud I don't see run by right clicking but I am able to click on Run tab --> Run.. (green button). Then it shows "Edit configuration". No option for the main class like it would if this was a normal Intellij program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have imported the project at the wrong folder level.
your folder structure seems to be like demo/demo/src.

You imported the project at `demo` whereas you should have imported it at `demo/demo`.
When you import it you want `src/` and `pom.xml` to be at the root of the project.
Also when you import it the `src/` folder should be blue, that is how you know you have imported it correctly.

[image]

As a rule of thumb you should always make sure a pom.xml is at the root of the import when working with maven

Comment: Thank you! Really helped

Answer (score 0):

you have to set project SDK first, then it can be run from main class.

1. File -> project structure -> project -> set project SDK from dropdown, download or browse jdk bin path

   short key: CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S
2. Go to the main class and run or add configuration from the menu